# After copying and pasting the target xls file does not have sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have code that copies record by record and pastes it in the target xls file, that is originally empty. It has like a newly created xls file, 3 empty sheets.

I did some adjustments and I started to get error.

```
Sub auto_close()

Dim linkSrcFile As String
Dim targetSrcFile As String

Dim currentFilePath As String

Dim wkbLink As Workbook
Dim targetWkb As Workbook

Dim wksLinkWkb As Worksheet 'Link document
Dim wksCurrent As Worksheet 'Current
Dim targetWks As Worksheet 'Target = Results

'Dim currentWks As Worksheet
Dim docname As String
Dim user As String

'File names
Dim linkDoc As String
Dim resultDoc As String

linkDoc = "Link document.xls"
resultDoc = "Results.xls"

'On Error GoTo ErrorHandling

'Set Paths
linkSrcFile = Replace(ThisWorkbook.FullName, ThisWorkbook.Name, linkDoc)
targetSrcFile = Replace(ThisWorkbook.FullName, ThisWorkbook.Name, resultDoc)

'Get workbooks
Set wkbLink = GetObject(linkSrcFile)
Set targetWkb = GetObject(targetSrcFile)

'Get worksheets
Set wksLinkWkb = wkbLink.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set wksCurrent = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set targetWks = targetWkb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim nbColumns As Integer
Dim nbForUnhiddenColumn As Integer

'Determing the amount of columns
nbColumns = Range("1:1").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count

'Checking for unhidden column
For i = 1 To nbColumns
    If Columns(i).Hidden = False Then
        Debug.Print "Column is not hidden"
        nbForUnhiddenColumn = i
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

'First row
'wksCurrent.Range("A1", "P1").Copy
wksCurrent.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 16)).Copy
targetWks.Range("A1", "P1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
targetWks.Range("Q1").Value = "User"

'Looping thru the records in Link xls file
For i = 2 To wksLinkWkb.Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count

    docname = wksLinkWkb.Cells(i, 3).Value
    user = wksLinkWkb.Cells(i, 2).Value

        'Looping thru Report.xls records
        For j = 2 To wksCurrent.Range(nbForUnhiddenColumn & ":" & nbForUnhiddenColumn).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
            If wksCurrent.Cells(j, "J").Value = docname Then
                Debug.Print "Match " & docname & " " & user
                wksCurrent.Range(Cells(j, 1), Cells(j, nbColumns)).Copy
                targetWks.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, nbColumns)).PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
                targetWks.Cells(i, nbColumns + 1).Value = user
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
Next i

targetWkb.Save
targetWkb.Close
wkbLink.Close False
Debug.Print "Target workbook saved and closed"

Exit_thisSub:
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandling:
    Dim strMsg As String
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 432
            strMsg = "Error occured: Make sure the names of the files are correct: " & linkDoc & " and " & resultDoc & " and they are in the same map, as this one (" & ThisWorkbook.Name & ")"
            MsgBox strMsg
            targetWkb.Close False
            wkbLink.Close False
        Case Else
            strMsg = "Error occured: " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
            MsgBox strMsg
            targetWkb.Close False
            wkbLink.Close False
    End Select
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

I did try to work with variables and not hard coded ranges but even if I change them to hardcoded values I still get an empty xls document without any sheets.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a master in VBA but I have an experiance of 2 to 3 months and I can help you to improvise your code, considering line on line. I dont know about other versions of excel but I work on 2003.

Some times I found run time errors using just workbook.I did not understand the reason so i opted to use Excel.Workbook

```
  Dim wkbLink As Workbook, make it as Dim wkbLink As Excel.Workbook Instead
```

Seeing your code, I guess you want to refer to the workbook try to use these.

```
Set wkbLink = GetObject(linkSrcFile)        ' I have no idea about this but
Set wkbLink = workbooks.open(linksSrcFile)  ' It works perfect.

Set targetWks = targetWkb.Worksheets("Sheet1")  ' right way 
Set targetWks = targetWkb.Worksheets(1) 'Can also refer to sheet 1 like these
```

To find the number of columns

```
nbColumns = Range("1:1").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count ' No idea
```

Use these

```
Columnz = Thisworkbook.workSheets(1).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
else
Thisworkbook.worksheets(1).activate
Columnz = Activesheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

I dont see what sheet your referring to find the number of columns , its hard to find out , try to reference to the object .

and

```
If Columns(i).Hidden = False Then   'make it as below
if activesheet.columns(i).Entirecolumn.Hidden= false then
```

It's not these

```
wksCurrent.Range("A1", "P1").Copy  ' its wrong make it like below
wksCurrent.Range("A1:P1").Copy
```

I am not understanding what your trying to do but I belive your are trying to copy row from A1:P1 to other sheet and you have to do these way

```
   wbk_1.sheets(1).range("A1:P1").copy
   wbk_2.sheets(1).activate
   activesheet.range("A1").select
   activesheet.paste ' now_wbk_2.sheets(1) has copied row in its first row
```

Probably, You are using these to find the number of rows

```
 wksLinkWkb.Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
```

You are not referring to any workbook i dont expect it to work.Use these

```
 Rowz = Thisworkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' to count no of rows
```

I have just answered for copy and paste modes try to read these answer of mine , it helps you [How can I copy between two open Excel instances in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867939/copy-data-from-already-opened-excel-to-another-already-opened-excel-in-vba/7872669#7872669)

Any more help . ask me I will help you. Thanks