# How can I copy between two open Excel instances in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to copy data from one already opened instance of Excel to another instance of Excel in VBA.  I tried:

```
Option Explicit
Sub copy_paste()

    Dim destination_sanitized As String
    Dim fs As New FileSystemObject

    destination_sanitized = fs.BuildPath("c:\temp\", "1.xlsx")

    Dim xl As New Excel.Application

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=destination_sanitized)

    Dim r1 As Range
    Dim r2 As Range
    Set r1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("hidden").Range("E10:E13")
    Set r2 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J20:J23")

    On Error GoTo Cleanup
    r1.Copy r2

Cleanup:
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Set xl = Nothing
    MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.description


End Sub
```

I get Run-time error '1004': Copy method of Range class failed

How can I copy data from one already opened instance of Excel to another Excel instance in VBA?

I understand how to do this when they are part of the same instance.  In this particular case, I need the two workbooks to be in separate instances.  I also need to do a full copy (Data Validation, Formulas, Values, Formats, etc), so r2.Value = r1.Value will not suffice.

Comment: by "However I am using atleast 10 excels simultaneously" do you mean you have 10 workbooks open in one instance of Excel, or ten separate instances opne?

Comment: When your problem is solved ,Accept some answers than we would try to suggest some codes

Comment: None of the proposed answers actually address the problem. The question is about copying and pasting between application instances. The proposed answers are for copying between different workbooks open in the same application instance.

Comment: @yu_ominae I beg to differ - my answer does actually copy between _instances_ not _workbooks_

Comment: @MacroMan Did you post your answer after my comment? I can't see the history, but it says answered in 2014.

Comment: @MacroMan No worries. It's good you have the comment there, so other users will know there is an answer available now.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to elaborate as to why you *need* separate instances, so far in my career I have never had any reason to use a separate instance in Excel and it is a nightmare for automation.

That being said, you can give something like this a try (assuming you only have 2 instances open):

```
Sub MM()

    Dim varTask As Variant
    Dim XL1 As Application, XL2 As Application
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
    Dim OtherWB As Workbook
    Dim destination_sanitized As String

    destination_sanitized = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").BuildPath("C:\temp\", "1.xlsx")

    With CreateObject("Word.Application")
       If .Tasks.Exists("Microsoft Excel") Then
           For Each varTask In .Tasks
           Debug.Print varTask
                 If InStr(varTask.Name, "Microsoft Excel") = 1 Then
                      If XL1 Is Nothing Then
                        Set XL1 = GetObject(Replace(varTask, "Microsoft Excel - ", "")).Application
                      Else
                        Set XL2 = GetObject(Replace(varTask, "Microsoft Excel - ", "")).Application
                      End If
                 End If
           Next varTask
       End If
       .Quit
    End With

    'Then something like...

    Set r1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("hidden").Range("E10:E13")
    Set OtherWB = XL2.Workbooks.Open(destination_sanitized)
    Set r2 = OtherWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J20:J23")
    r1.Copy r2

    'Clear down memory afterwards
    Set r1 = Nothing
    Set r2 = Nothing
    OtherWB.Close False
    Set OtherWB = Nothing
    Set XL1 = Nothing
    XL2.Quit
    Set XL2 = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to get two instances of Excel to talk to each other in all situations. You can find the other running instances, but there are too many things to consider.

In similar cases I keep it simple and make two buttons:

- **Export** that saves to clipboard.csv or clipboard.xlsx or whatever
  format you like the data to copy
- **Import** that gets the data from the clipboard temporary file

The user is in charge of clicking on the Export button on one instance, then on the Import button on the second instance.